# set value for a label without connection using code

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to set value for uilabel using objective-c without any connection from storyboard to source-file.
In a storyboard, suppose a label is dropped into uiview and we don't want to bound connection to .h file , so how is it possible to set value using objective-c.

Comment: Why? Ok, let's put the 'why' aside. First, you can connect also to the .m-file. Second, you can set the `tag` of the label and access it with `viewWithTag`. But it sounds like you try to fight the frameworks and this is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UILabel Programatically like,

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 15, 0, 0)];
myLabel.text = @"hello";
[self.view addSybview:myLabel];
```

Second thing you can set tag from storyboard and by this tag you can access label.

Third thing you can get `NSArray` of subviews of self.view means your main view and from that array you can access that label.

these are the possible ways. :)

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `tag` value to your `UILabel` from the storyboard, then you can use that value to access the view from your code:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:1];
[label setText:@"setting some value"];
```